# JavaScript for loops and intervals between increments

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to create a small tool to help visualize nested for-loops. The tool would look something like this but with multiple rows of circles:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLTX/

```
var sequenceTrack1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

//START TRACK1 Code//
var counterTrackOne = 0;

function iterateTrackOne() {
    if (sequenceTrack1.length > counterTrackOne) {
        counterTrackOne++;
        $("#track1_Step" + [counterTrackOne]).effect("highlight", {
            color: "#749CD5"
        });

        setTimeout(iterateTrackOne, 1000);
        if (counterTrackOne === sequenceTrack1.length) {
            counterTrackOne = 0;
        }
    }

};
iterateTrackOne();
```

However when I wrote the above code I did not use any for-loops and would like to refactor it as such. My first step is to simply use a for-loop to run a console log message at timed intervals. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: your idea doesn't fit neatly into the js event-oriented procesing paradigm. rather try to setup an interval timer ( example: `var handle = setInterval ( function () { console.log("whatever"); }, 1000);` which outputs a message every second. terminate the handler using `clearInterval(handle);` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not following your code 100%, but is this what you want to do?

I don't know if you intend to iterate infinitely.

My guess is that you only want to iterate once since your function name says so.

Here's my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/5jNXv/2/

```
var sequenceTrack1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

//START TRACK1 Code//

for (var i = 0, l = sequenceTrack1.length; i < l; i++) {
    setTimeout((function (i) {
        return function () {
            $("#track1_Step" + sequenceTrack1[i]).effect("highlight", {
                color: "#749CD5"
            });
        };
    })(i), 1000 * i);
}
```

Comment: This works but its a bit uglier than I had hoped for. I intended to have nested for loops and output in a manner that helps demonstrate the relationships between them.